# Error in gradle when build my project ionic 4 corvova android, anyone help me?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, gradle, build.gradle

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\alan-\Desktop\Epacv1\platforms\android\app\build.gradle' line: 20
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

  > Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.internal.version-check']
  >   Minimum supported Gradle version is 5.6.1. Current version is 4.10.3. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in C:\Users\alan-\Desktop\Epacv1\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-5.6.1-all.zip
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
C:\Users\alan-\Desktop\Epacv1\platforms\android\gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\alan-\Desktop\Epacv1\platforms\android\app\build.gradle' line: 20
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

  > Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.internal.version-check']
  >   Minimum supported Gradle version is 5.6.1. Current version is 4.10.3. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in C:\Users\alan-\Desktop\Epacv1\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-5.6.1-all.zip
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

---

I already installed version 5.6.2 already changed what it asks for, but it is still reading version 4.10.3.

Answer (score 2):

Go to below path in your ionic cordova project

Path : Drive\Your project folder\platforms\android\cordova\lib\builders\GradleBuilder.js

Change minimum supported Gradle version to 5.6.1 there,this will reflect in your project and your project will read 5.6.1 instead of 4.10.3.

> > > > In Ionic 4,Change minimum supported gradle version in ProjectBuilder.js in builders folder,then build the app

Comment: As of June 2020, cordova@9 and cordova-android@8, Path is : Drive\Your project folder\platforms\android\cordova\lib\builders\ProjectBuiler.js    5.6.4 is minimum required, update as below.
https\\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check your **plaforms/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties** file what is the **distributionUrl** ?